# Autofill textbox using jQuery DatePicker. Calendar displaying at bottom of screen. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to autopopulate a textbox with the current date. For some reason when I do this, a calendar is at the bottom of the screen like this:

[image]

Other than this, the code is working properly. I'm testing code in Google Chrome. Here's the jQuery I have tried:

```
//option 1
$(".pickDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());

//option 2
$(".pickDate").datepicker();
$(".pickDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

When code is just

```
    $(".pickDate").datepicker();
```

The mystery calendar disappears but DatePicker continues to work. Could someone please explain what is going on? I have double checked my HTML code to ensure that there is no extra .pickDate selector hiding in the code.

Comment: Have you tried to use defaultDate instead of setDate? If setDate does not work defaultDate can be a good workaround. 
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() });

Comment: As for why that is happening, what is your Jquery Ui version? Updating to the latest version of Jquery Ui may help this issue as well.

Comment: Anything UI related and position is caused by pulling in the UI file before the jquery script for example or an out of date file inclusion.

Comment: According to the NuGet Manager, my jQuery UI is 1.12.1, so it's current. $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: new Date() }); isn't auto-filling the date into the textbox. It is working just the same as $( ".selector" ).datepicker();